# Excluding params in Java generic class

Tags: java, generics

I've got three classes: A, B and C. **C** extends **B**, **B** extends **A**.
Also I've got generic class **indClass2** with the following code:

**indClass2.java**

```
package myproject;

public class indClass2 <T extends A> {

    static void hello(indClass2<? super B> a){
        System.out.println("hello from super B");
    }
    static void hello(indClass2<? extends B> a){
        System.out.println("hello from extends B");
    }

}
```

`indClass2<? super B>` and `indClass2<? extends B>` are excluding each other.

**helloworld.java**

```
package myproject;

public class helloworld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        indClass2<A> a = new indClass2<A>();
        indClass2<B> b = new indClass2<B>();
        indClass2<C> c = new indClass2<C>();

        indClass2.hello(a);
        indClass2.hello(b);
        indClass2.hello(c);

    }
}
```

I've got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
Unresolved compilation problem:
The method hello(indClass2<? super B>) in the type indClass2 is not applicable for the arguments (indClass2<C>)

    at myproject.helloworld.main(helloworld.java:12)
```

How could I realise `hello()` in **indClass2** for both?

Comment: Java generics are compile time (aka erasure) - how would it know which overload to choose at runtime? All `hello` calls and methods compile to the same code.

Comment: Don't try running code that doesn't compile. That makes no sense. Rename one of your methods. BTW, classes should start with an uppercase letter and have a meaningful name. And there is no reason for indClass2 to be generic. It does never use its T  generic type.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> `indClass2<? super B>` and `indClass2<? extends B>` are excluding each other.

It looks like they are excluding each other, but not in the Java World!

Both of these has the same erasure and these methods have exactly the same signature and hence you will get a compilation error.

```
name clash: hello(indClass2<? extends B>) and hello(indClass2<? super B>) 
have the same erasure
```

If you are doing this to understand/learn more about Java or Type Erasure then read the official documentation here:

- [Effect of Type Erasure and Bridge Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)
- [Erasure of Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html)

Or a deep analysis done in this [Blog: Type Erasure](http://javapapers.com/core-java/type-erasure/)

Comment: `indClass2<? super B>` and `indClass2<? extends B>` don't exclude each other: they are overlapping sets.

Comment: Doesn't `B` match both sets?

Comment: I was trying to requote the statement in the question.  
    `indClass2<? super B> and indClass2<? extends B> are excluding each other.`

Answer (score 0):

If you compile the code, you can see `erasure` acting up :)

```
error: name clash: hello(indClass2<? extends B>) and hello(indClass2<? super B>) have the same erasure
    static void hello(indClass2<? extends B> a){
```